# Serialize bool to string

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, xml-serialization

I have a bool property.

How can I decorate it to serialize in xml into char insetead of bool? I mean for `true` should be `Y`, for `false` should be `N`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[XmlIgnore]
public bool Foo {get;set;}

[XmlElement("Foo"), Browsable(false)]
//or: [XmlAttribute("Foo"), Browsable(false)]
public string FooSerialized {
    get { return Foo ? "Y" : "N"; }
    set {
        switch(value) {
            case "Y": Foo = true; break;
            case "N": Foo = false; break;
            default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
}
```